# how to include a external js file in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular2. I need to add Google map library in one page and in another page fusion chart library. One thing I can do is to add all those in index.html where my all the pages will show. But I want to add libraries in particular pages.
How to add libraries in particular page partials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your terminal window, locate to your project directory, where `package.json` is placed. Then run the following command to install fusion-charts:

```
npm install angular2-fusioncharts --save-dev
```

To include that in a your app, add the following in your `AppModule`:

```
// Import angular2-fusioncharts
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular2-fusioncharts';

// Import FusionCharts library
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
```

Now you can use fusion-charts throughout your app. You dont have to add any link in your `index.html`. You can do the same for using google-maps ([getting started guide](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/)).

Here is a link to [angular2-fusioncharts](https://github.com/fusioncharts/angular2-fusioncharts) github repository.